# References in Sylow's theorems, solvable groups, nilpotent group and Frattini subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm very interested in group theory, i.e Sylow's theorems, solvable groups, nilpotent group and Frattini subgroups. Can anyone tell me some articles, textbooks, notes ... about them?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Isaac's book, Rotman's book, Robinson's book (all this in group theory), Dummit&Foote's book, Hungerford's book (in abstract algebra)...all these are classics.

Comment: First six chapters of Dummit and Foote will give you a lot of stuff. That book can be a little daunting to a beginner, but it sounds like you are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text *Finite Group Theory* by I. Martin Isaacs covers the sort of topics you mention here and seems like it might be the right flavor.  It has good exposition and quite a few nice problems with hints.

Comment: I remember having a tough time with Isaacs when I first read it, but then later I came to appreciate it more. So, this is a good recommendation. The only thing I still don't like a whole lot about Isaacs's book is the exercises, but this is easily remedied with the internet and with other books :)

Comment: @universalset: +1 vote: Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend Keith Conrad's homepage / [expository papers](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/)! There are three well-written papers on Sylow theory. And a lot more!